# What do you call a nearly vertical step on a ridge?

Tags: rock-climbing

Here is an example where someone climbing strictly on the ridge would encounter a vertical section:

[image]

What do you call this feature?

Comment: Pretty hard to tell from that perspective just how 'vertical' it is up close.

Comment: @JonCuster It starts at 60-70 deg., but the top 20 ft. is vertical with some overhang. I bypassed it to climber's left.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would call it a "step" just like you have done.

There is historical precedent for this, with the most famous one being the [Hillary Step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillary_Step) at 8,790 m (28,839 feet) on [Mount Everest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Everest) named after Sir [Edmund Hillary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Hillary), who, along with [Tenzing Norgay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenzing_Norgay) were the first known people to climb it in their 1953 ascent of Everest.

Comment: The Hillary Step came to mind to me as well. From `Into Thin Air` it's not a trivial piece of work given the altitude.

Answer (score 3):

Features like this are also sometimes called a [Gendarme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gendarme_(mountaineering))

Comment: Wouldn't a Gendarme imply a pillar/pinnacle, rather than a step?